# How to set up an environment variable in mvn pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How can i set up an environment variable (in other words internally accessible by `System.getenv("APP_HOME")` in a pom file?

```
APP_HOME=/path/home
```

I realize i can set it up in `.profile`, but wonder if pom can do the same trick.

Per bmargulies's suggestion below, i tried the following, without luck

```
<build>
    <finalName>KvpStore</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <APP_NAME>blah_blah</APP_NAME>  <------------------------
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The [documentation of the maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) show examples and describes how to do such things of setting up system properties.

```
<configuration>
  <systemPropertyVariables>
    <propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName>
    <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
    [...]
  </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

It might be better to use them instead of environment variable, cause it's simpler to use them, cause env variable needed to setup correctly and the cmd.exe and the jvm must be restarted to get them working.

It is not necessary to configure the includes for the tests, cause [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) has already the following defaults:

```
<includes>
 <include>**/Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: The OP asked for env vars, not Java system properties.

Comment: I know but env variables make more problems than system properties.

Comment: I guess that he or she is launching processes that really read env vars.

Comment: cause != because

Answer (score 57):

Some plugins, like surefire, let you set them. There's no way, in general, in the pom.

The doc for surefire is is [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables). Surefire will set environment variables for the duration of the run of the tests, not for anything else. And you have to make surefire fork.

In the configuration ...

```
<configuration>
  <forkMode>always</forkMode>
  <environmentVariables>
     <var1>val1</var1>
  </environmentVariables>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm .. does not seem to work. I assume <var> is the name of the key?

Comment: Use mvn -X to check what's happening.

Comment: Have you restarted the cmd.exe before trying this ? Are you calling from command line or from Eclipse ?

Comment: This won't side-effect the command-line or anywhere else. It will only effect the tests.

Comment: if forkmode is disabled, you can use systemPropertyVariables instead to make it work. but make sure to read it via getProperty and not getEnv

Comment: Then it's not an env variable any more, but merely a Java system property.

Comment: Using <environmentVariables> works for me when using System.getenv(). This is the correct answer.

Comment: How to refer a POM property value in `<environmentVariables>`? I'm trying to refer to one, but its setting `${env}` as value of environment variable.