# Setting Environment Variables in Maven pom files

Tags: maven

Sorry for asking a question that many will say it has been asked again and again, however I couldn't find a satisfactory or complete answer.

I have to build a maven project. Inside it I have the following:

```
<profile>
  <id>windows</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>Windows</family>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <weblogic.home>${env.WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME}</weblogic.home>
    <weblogic.precompilation.java.home>${env.JAVA_64_HOME}</weblogic.precompilation.java.home>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

and I get the error:

```
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for weblogic:weblogic.jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar @ ..\pom.xml
```

Of course, by setting the absolute path to the above:

```
<weblogic.home>c:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3</weblogic.home>
```

the problem is solved, but how can I actually set `env.WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME` in my system so that maven finds it?

I setup a new environment variable:

```
WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME = c:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3
```

in my Windows machine but no luck. I tried setting `configuration` `environmentVariables` in `maven-surefire-plugin` as explained in [[How to set up an environment variable in mvn pom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027003/how-to-set-up-an-environment-variable-in-mvn-pom]) (but didn't pass it via -D in the command line), tried to set a property like here [[How to refer environment variable in POM.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml]) but no chance.

I thought that once I setup the environment variable (`WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME`) in my OS, I could then access it from my pom using `${env.WEBLOGIC_SERVER_HOME}`. But I guess this is not enough.

In my IDE (NetBeans), I cannot set the environment variable for the maven project since it displays the "Resolve Project Problems" dialog box instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the whole pom.xml or the dependencyManagement section, where you are probably defining the weblogic dependency?

Comment: I would suggest to upload the weblogic.jar to a repository manager and set the dependency in your pom to `<scope>provided</scope>` than you will get be rid of the environment variables...